# Do Phoenixes have souls?

Tags: harry-potter, phoenix, souls

In Harry Potter universe, do Phoenixes have souls?

Canon based answers only please.

Comment: Bonus question: If so, is the soul preserved during re-birth?

Comment: I would imagine that animals do have souls in HP. Having a living being as a Horcrux is implied to be risky, which suggests that animals might have a soul of their own. But that’s pure guesswork.

Comment: @Himarm - what does magic or longevity have to do with soul? Non-living objects have magical properties too.

Comment: I would view the Phoenix to not have a soul, because things with a soul either go to Heaven or Hell when they die, but a Phoenix doesn't die

Comment: @DVK I believe the plural for Phoenix is "Phoenices"

Comment: @WadCheber - if you have a decent reference to prove it, feel free to edit the correct spelling. I'm ESL :)

Answer (score 6):

It seems clear from the Harry Potter books and films that animals (or at least certain animals) have souls and can become ghosts.

Members of the Headless hunt, for example ride on ghostly horses:

> Through the dungeon wall burst a dozen ghost horses, each ridden by a
>   headless horseman. The assembly clapped wildly; Harry started to clap
>   too, but stopped quickly at the sight of Nick’s face. The horses
>   galloped into the middle of the dance floor and halted, rearing and
>   plunging; a large ghost at the front, whose bearded head was under his
>   arm, blowing the horn, leapt down, lifted his head high in the air so
>   he could see over the crowd (everyone laughed) and strode over to
>   Nearly Headless Nick, squashing his head back onto his neck <sub><sup>Chamber of Secrets</sup></sub>

and Mopsy Fleabert has written an *entire book* about animal spirits.

> Read more from Mopsy Fleabert about animal spirits and how to
>   recognize them. <sub><sup>[Pottermore Wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Animal_Ghosts_of_Britain)</sup></sub>

Since becoming a ghost seems to be a function of having a soul in the first place, it seems likely that some if not *all* animals in the Potter universe have souls, Phoenixes included.