# Why was the procedure and the outcome for the 7th "horcrux" so different from the other 6?

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux

When Voldemort created the first 6 Horcruxes, he did not need to put his soul inside another living body.  A simple object easily works well enough (like Gaunt's ring). When he created the 7th (baby Harry) it says his soul had to latch ***onto a living thing***.....?

Is there an actual reason his soul could not have simply bounced into a random non-living object like **all the other Horcruxes** ever made? Why, in this one case only, could him killing something (himself) cause his soul not to be able to simply bounce into an object?

Comment: You've claimed to be a potter trivia master, but then go on to say when Voldemort *created the 7th [horcrux]* when in fact he didn't intend to create that "horcrux", and Harry wasn't a horcrux [it is clear Harry was not a Horcrux](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/11546/68872)

Comment: You spelled Voldemort wrong. Also "Morphin's ring" isn't a thing in Potterverse as far as I'm aware of. Please turn in your "Harry Potter trivia master" card.

Comment: Related: [Is a living being a poor choice for a Horcrux?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/8549/21267)

Comment: Heavily related, not dupe; [Why didn't Voldemort's soul attach to any other living thing except Harry?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/147260/why-didnt-voldemorts-soul-attach-to-any-other-living-thing-except-harry)

Answer (score 3):

## The difference may be because it wasn’t an intentional Horcrux.

When Horcruxes are created from inanimate objects, it’s intentional, and the wizard creating them has to actually do something (though we don’t know what) to seal the piece of soul in the object.

With Harry, the Dark Lord took no intentional action to put a piece of his soul in Harry. It’s therefore possible that the soul piece, of its own accord, chose to “possess” a living thing rather than an inanimate object.

It certainly seems to be easier for soul pieces to possess living things than inanimate objects. Even the soul pieces in the inanimate intentional Horcruxes can possess people temporarily, though they’re dependent on the objects for survival.

> “And once the diary was properly destroyed, the bit of soul trapped in it could no longer exist. Ginny tried to get rid of the diary before you did, flushing it away, but, obviously, it came back good as new.’
>
> ‘Hang on,’ said Ron, frowning. ‘The bit of soul in that diary was possessing Ginny, wasn’t it? How does that work, then?’
>
> ‘While the magical container is still intact, the bit of soul inside it can flit in and out of someone if they get too close to the object.”

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/147260/why-didnt-voldemorts-soul-attach-to-any-other-living-thing-except-harry

Answer (score 2):

> 'And they could be anything?' said Harry. 'They could be oh, in tin cans or, I dunno, empty potion bottles...'
> 'You are thinking of Portkeys, Harry, which must be ordinary objects, easy to overlook. But would Lord Voldemort use tin cans or old potion bottles to guard his own precious soul? You are forgetting what I have showed you. Lord Voldemort liked to collect trophies, and he preferred objects with a powerful magical history His pride, his belief in his own superiority, his determination to carve for himself a startling place in magical history; these things, suggest to me that Voldemort would have chosen his Horcruxes with some care, favouring objects worthy of the honour.'

This implies that he intentionally made horcruxes out of important objects instead of ordinary ones, it could be that when he created harry unintentionally, this was unconsciously carried over and the horcrux had to be something special, and what more special thing was in that room than a baby wizard with his mom's love spell on him?

 A part of his soul was split and was looking for a host, and the soul of a bigoted elitist like Voldemort wouldn't be happy with an ordinary object found in a normal house, i believe that the soul fragment acted without Voldemort's knowing but with his predispositions and personality.

 And also, obviously a soul is meant to be inside a living body, you have to do special actions to fit it inside an object and create a horcrux, actions Voldemort obviously didn't do before he killed lily, so when the soul fragment is trying to latch onto sth, it can't latch onto any object, because that's just not how it works, the most suitable environment would be a human body and that's where it went.

Answer (score 1):

To create a horcrux, you need preparation, I don't recall where I heard this, but I believe that JK Rowling said  that you need to do other things to create a horcrux besides killing a human and casting a spell.

What do you think is the natural container for a soul? If another part of Voldemort's soul tore and latched onto something because of his soul's instability, you would assume it would latch onto the best and most natural container for it. This is purely speculation on my part, but I think it's because Voldemort's torn piece of soul latched onto the most fit container for a soul, a body.